# .NET Sample Project Design Patterns Fowler

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, projects, sample, poeaa

Are there sample ASP.NET projects around using the patterns discussed in the book by Martin Fowler ([Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420))?

I have downloaded the Northwind starters kit and Dinner Now, which are very good. Are there others that use things like Unit of Work, Repository, ...

thx, Lieven Cardoen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dofactory.com](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) as C# and VB.NET GoF pattern examples. They also have a full ASP.NET web application example detailing the use of the patterns, although I don't think that is a free download.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe have a look at [cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/).  It uses NHibernate (which is an implementation of the UnitOfWork pattern (and it also uses the identity map pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The [Composite Client Application Guidance for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707819.aspx) has some examples of unit testing and nHibernate.

Also, if your looking for good nHibernate screencasts check out the [Summer of nHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)